# Remove border from UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibezierpath

I have drawn a very simple path using a UIBezierPath and a custom UIView subclass but for some reason, a border appears around the bounds of the view and I cannot seem to get rid of it or see why it was created.

I used this code:

```
private override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
  let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 15, y: 15, width: 300, height: 300))

  path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
  path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150))
  path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 200))
  path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 150, y: 250))

  path.lineWidth = 25.0

  UIColor.darkGray.setStroke()
  path.stroke()
}
```

and it gave this result... (the border should not be there, only the zig-zag line)

[image: result]

Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating that rectangle by

```
let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 15, y: 15, width: 300, height: 300))
```

you just need to do

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
```

Answer (score 3):

You are initialising the path with a rect, which gets drawn with the stroke.
Just replace your first line with this:

`let path = UIBezierPath()`